# Is there a way to plug two monitors into a single laptop VGA port?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

Is there some kind of reverse splitter so I can plug two monitors into my laptop's VGA port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Matrox DualHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/) is a device which sells for about $200 in the US, and allows you to connect 2 monitors to the VGA output port of your laptop. (Matrox also has a TripleHead2Go which, naturally, allows for up to 3 monitors to be so connected.)

Comment: Cool, I just bought one on eBay!